# Unrecognized module map file Release-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap' not found

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have created a new react-native project and I am trying to build the iOS code but it is failing with below error:

fatal error: module map file

```
'/Users/ritz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/thoughtrail-blthhaitoghgvzenyxayuwazwzfm/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap' not found
```

react-native versions:
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.62.2

stack trace from Xcode:

```
CompileC /Users/ritz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/thoughtrail-blthhaitoghgvzenyxayuwazwzfm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/thoughtrail.build/Release-iphonesimulator/thoughtrail.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/thoughtrail_vers.o /Users/ritz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/thoughtrail-blthhaitoghgvzenyxayuwazwzfm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/thoughtrail.build/Release-iphonesimulator/thoughtrail.build/DerivedSources/thoughtrail_vers.c normal x86_64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'thoughtrail' from project 'thoughtrail')
    cd /Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c -target x86_64-apple-ios9.0-simulator -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/ritz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/ritz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -DCOCOAPODS=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.4.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -iquote /Users/ritz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/thoughtrail-blthhaitoghgvzenyxayuwazwzfm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/thoughtrail.build/Release-iphonesimulator/thoughtrail.build/thoughtrail-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/ritz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/thoughtrail-blthhaitoghgvzenyxayuwazwzfm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/thoughtrail.build/Release-iphonesimulator/thoughtrail.build/thoughtrail-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/ritz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/thoughtrail-blthhaitoghgvzenyxayuwazwzfm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/thoughtrail.build/Release-iphonesimulator/thoughtrail.build/thoughtrail-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/ritz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/thoughtrail-blthhaitoghgvzenyxayuwazwzfm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/thoughtrail.build/Release-iphonesimulator/thoughtrail.build/thoughtrail-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/ritz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/thoughtrail-blthhaitoghgvzenyxayuwazwzfm/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaAsyncSocket -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaLibEvent -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/DoubleConversion -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FBLazyVector -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FBReactNativeSpec -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-DoubleConversion -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-Folly -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-Glog -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-PeerTalk -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-RSocket -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FlipperKit -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/OpenSSL-Universal -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCTRequired -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCTTypeSafety -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-RCTText -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-cxxreact -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsi -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsiexecutor -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsinspector -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/ReactCommon -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Yoga -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/YogaKit -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/glog -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/react-native-webview -I/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/React-Core -I/Users/ritz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/thoughtrail-blthhaitoghgvzenyxayuwazwzfm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/thoughtrail.build/Release-iphonesimulator/thoughtrail.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -I/Users/ritz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/thoughtrail-blthhaitoghgvzenyxayuwazwzfm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/thoughtrail.build/Release-iphonesimulator/thoughtrail.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/ritz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/thoughtrail-blthhaitoghgvzenyxayuwazwzfm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/thoughtrail.build/Release-iphonesimulator/thoughtrail.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/ritz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/thoughtrail-blthhaitoghgvzenyxayuwazwzfm/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator -fmodule-map-file=/Users/ritz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/thoughtrail-blthhaitoghgvzenyxayuwazwzfm/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap -fmodule-map-file=/Users/ritz/Documents/workspace/threesixnine/thoughtrail/source/mobile/thoughtrail/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/yoga/Yoga.modulemap -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/ritz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/thoughtrail-blthhaitoghgvzenyxayuwazwzfm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/thoughtrail.build/Release-iphonesimulator/thoughtrail.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/thoughtrail_vers.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/ritz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/thoughtrail-blthhaitoghgvzenyxayuwazwzfm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/thoughtrail.build/Release-iphonesimulator/thoughtrail.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/thoughtrail_vers.dia -c /Users/ritz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/thoughtrail-blthhaitoghgvzenyxayuwazwzfm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/thoughtrail.build/Release-iphonesimulator/thoughtrail.build/DerivedSources/thoughtrail_vers.c -o /Users/ritz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/thoughtrail-blthhaitoghgvzenyxayuwazwzfm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/thoughtrail.build/Release-iphonesimulator/thoughtrail.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/thoughtrail_vers.o
```

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 16):

Found the problems:

1. I opened a `xcproject` file instead of `xcworkspace`. Since I am using react-native which in turn uses COCOA, I am required to open the `xcworkspace`.
2. Reason for the above error was the POD Target Usable files were not available in the runtime project build directory generated.

So I Copy target support files from PODS Directory to dynamic generated path something like below
`/Users/ritz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/thoughtrail-blthhaitoghgvzenyxayuwazwzfm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator`

the build moved forward however it failed for some other reason.

So to summarize the problem was basically me opening the xcproject and not xcworkspace.

Hope this will help beginners like me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but its why I was Building from Xcode Project, and I have to do it from XCode Workspace.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting this error when trying to build the workspace from the command line. To fix it for me I needed to add `-workspace <AppName>.xcworkspace` to the end of my build command. I was able to figure this out thanks to the answers above regarding building from the IDE.

The failing command:

```
xcodebuild clean archive 
  -scheme releaseScheme 
  -configuration Release 
  -archivePath ../builds/<AppName>.xcarchive 
  -allowProvisioningUpdates
  DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=<TeamId>
```

The final command:

```
xcodebuild clean archive 
  -scheme releaseScheme 
  -configuration Release 
  -archivePath ../builds/<AppName>.xcarchive 
  -allowProvisioningUpdates
  -workspace <AppName>.xcworkspace
  DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=<TeamId>
```